# Compute the volume of region

Tags: calculus

> Compute the volume of region between the plane $x = 1$ and paraboloid $x = 5 − y^2-z^2$.

I know this should be a triple integral, and it seems as though I should be using polar coordinates to solve this, but I don't have any way to obtain $x^2+y^2=r^2$. How do I start this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we find the intersection of the two surfaces: $1 = 5-y^2-z^2 \to y^2+z^2 =4$, a circle centered at $(0,0)$ in the $yz$ plane having radius $r= 2$. Using cylindrical coordinates we have the sought after volume is :

$\text{V} = \displaystyle \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^2 \int_{x=1}^{5-r^2}rdxdrd\theta$

Answer (score 0):

"Polar" coordinates in three dimensions (actually cylindrical coordinates) do not *have* to use the $z$ axis as the "$r = 0$" locus.
You can make cylindrical coordinates around the $y$ axis by setting $r^2 = x^2 + z^2,$
or around the $x$ axis by setting $r^2 = y^2 + z^2.$
Choose the coordinate axis that makes $r^2$ look the most like something in
the equation of your paraboloid, if you can.

Since a paraboloid is a solid of rotation, you might alternatively be able to use a "disk" method.